# How to show child site tags in parent site tag cloud?

Tags: liferay, hook

I'm hooking the tag cloud portlet, but I can't figure out how to show the tags given to content in a child site. On one page, I have a tag cloud and an asset publisher below that showing tagged content if a tag is clicked. Currently the child site and parent site tags and contents are serparated.

In the tag cloud portlet options I see a global scope option, but that displays nothing. In `asset_tags_navigation/page.jsp` I see the following is used to actually get the tag data:

```
if (showAssetCount && (classNameId > 0)) {
  tags = AssetTagServiceUtil.getTags(scopeGroupId, classNameId, null, 0, maxAssetTags, new AssetTagCountComparator());
}
else {
  tags = AssetTagServiceUtil.getGroupTags(siteGroupId, 0, maxAssetTags, new AssetTagCountComparator());
}
```

How can I include the child site tags too? I need the asset publisher to display the child site content as well. Any options are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such builtin function. You will have to find all child groups using `GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroups(long companyId, long parentGroupId, boolean site)` (possibly recursive), resolve all tags with `AssetTagServiceUtil.getGroupsTags(long[] groupIds)` and sort and cut them by yourself.